Custom style for `tcolorbox` environment and `tcbsubskin` variable
I tried to create a style to simplify the definition of my tcolorbox environments, which will all follow the same format with one exception : the before upper option is variable. So I tried to add an option in the definition of my style, but I encountered several errors, which I expected, of course...
I really don't know how to go about doing this, not at all...
\tcbsubskin{environment}[1]{standard}{blanker,enlarge top by=2.5pt,enlarge bottom by=2.5pt,coltext=white,left=14pt,before upper=\textbf{#1}}
\newtcolorbox{CustomEnv}[1][]{environment{<text_to_be_used_as_value_for_the_before_upper_option>},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{CustomEnv}
<text_to_appear_after_the_text_set_with_the_before_upper_option>
\end{CustomEnv}

\end{document}


Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, instead of a code snippet.

a subskin must not change the boundary box so must not use any geometry commands. so that leaves at most blanker,coltext=white,before upper=\textbf{#1} as at least the remaining settings are invalid. what is supposed to be passed to before upper here? also, don't use environment as the subskin name. that's just asking for trouble. (I mean, hopefully tcolorbox uses a prefix or something, but it is still a bad idea.)
